# Best way to add an array of objects to a list of extended objects

Tags: c#

I have an Array `Customers[]` named 'customerArray' and I have a Generic List `List<ExtendedCustomers>` named 'extendedCustomerList'

The `ExtendedCustomer` class contains some properties, and one of them is 'Customer' (Yes, thats the same as the objects in the array), like this:

```
public class ExtendedCustomer {
     public Customer { get; set; }
     public OtherProperty { get; set; }
     ....
}
```

What is the fastest / best / easiest / best performing / most beautiful way to add the array with Customers to the list with ExtendedCustomers? The other properties in ExtendedCustomer can keep ther default NULL value.

<sub>I don't like loops</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) with a projection from customers to extended customers:

```
extendedCustomerList.AddRange(customerArray.Select(
    c => new ExtendedCustomer() {
        Customer = c
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Customer[] customers = ...;
List<ExtendedCustomer> extendedCustomers = ...;
extendedCustomers.AddRange(
       customers.Select(c => new ExtendedCustomer{ Customer = c }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
extendedCustomerList.AddRange(
    from customer in customerArray
    select new ExtendedCustomer {
        Customer = customer
    }
);
```